# Fluent Validation w/ MVC 5 using Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, fluentvalidation

Do I need to add "AssemblyScanner.FindValidatorsInAssemblyContaining" for every object validator I create? Is there a simpler way?

```
public class FluentValidatorModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        AssemblyScanner.FindValidatorsInAssemblyContaining<OfficeModelValidator>()
            .ForEach(match => Bind(match.InterfaceType).To(match.ValidatorType));
    }
}
```

Also, when I perform submit, the CreateInstance method in my NinjectValidatorFactory keeps getting called multiple times during one postback. Why is that happening?

```
public class NinjectValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    private IKernel _kernel;

    public NinjectValidatorFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
        AddBindings();
    }

    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {
        var bindings = (IEnumerable<IBinding>)_kernel.GetBindings(validatorType);
        return bindings.Count() > 0 ? _kernel.Get(validatorType) as IValidator : null;
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        _kernel.Bind<ILookupService>().To<LookupService>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `AssemblyScanner` is to scan through the assembly of the passed in type, allowing you to autobind all of them. In your example, `OfficeModelValidator` is just used to find the assembly where all your validators are defined.

refer to the source: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation/AssemblyScanner.cs